# Reorder array but don't change keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

E.g .I have this array:

```
$myArray = (

  [0] => 'First',
  [1] => 'Second',
  [2] => 'Third',
  [3] => 'Fourth'

);
```

And I need to get this:

```
$myArray = (

  [0] => 'Fourth',
  [1] => 'Third',
  [2] => 'Second',
  [3] => 'First'

);
```

So, I can stored it in my database in reverse order when compared with the original array.

I have tried `krsort($myArray);` but the result is not what I want, because it creates something like this:

```
$myArray = (

  [3] => 'Fourth',
  [2] => 'Third',
  [1] => 'Second',
  [0] => 'First'

);
```

And I want the keys stay as in original array.

And the problem is that I can not sort values e.g. by letters using arsort() etc. because they are different (different strings, without any meaning or order system).

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I have checked asort,arsort,ksort,krsort nothing works like I want to.

Comment: Wouldn't `krsort($myArray); $myArray = array_values($myArray)` work?  Or even `$myArray = array_reverse($myArray);`

Comment: $newarray = array_reverse ($amyArray);

Comment: @user4035 What? It's reversed. Check again!

Comment: So this entire question could be written as “how can I reverse an array in PHP”? [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/array_reverse)

Comment: @Derfder See it, sorry

Comment: Can't use sort() etc as they sort on the values in which case it'd be first, forth, second, third as it'd sort the values on alphabetical you can either do as below and break out all the keys / values pairs or simply just reverse the array and create a new array :)

Comment: You're saying that you want the keys to stay the same, but obviously what you want is the keys to NOT stay the same, otherwise `[3] => 'Fourth'` would be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to reverse an array, just use [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/array_reverse).

```
$myArray = array_reverse($myArray);
```

Result:

```
array (
    [0] => Fourth
    [1] => Third
    [2] => Second
    [3] => First
)
```